# Pick image from Gallery - File not found when running newer Android versions

Tags: android

I am working on a address book like Android SDK 14+ app. The users should be able to pick an image from the Gallery to add it to a contact entry.

Running the following code to pick and copy the image is no problem in API 14-20 but does not work in API 21+. The file is not found anymore:

```
protected void pickFoto() {
    if (filePermissionsRequired()) {
        askForFilePermissions(new PermissionRequestCompletionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequestResult(boolean permissionGranted) {
                if (permissionGranted)
                    addOrEditReceipt();
            }
        });
        return;
    }

    Intent pickPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickPhotoIntent , PICK_FOTO_ACTION);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); 

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            ...
            case PICK_FOTO_ACTION: {
                Uri imageUri = intent.getData();

                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                File imgFile = new File(filePath);
                if (imgFile.exists()) 
                    // use the file...
                else 
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image file not found",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
        }
    }



public interface PermissionRequestCompletionHandler {
    void onPermissionRequestResult(boolean permissionGranted);
}

private PermissionRequestCompletionHandler permissionRequestCompletionHandler;
public boolean filePermissionsRequired() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        return checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    else
        return false;
}

public boolean askForFilePermissions(PermissionRequestCompletionHandler completionHandler) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        permissionRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
        boolean hasPermission = this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        if (!hasPermission) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }

    permissionRequestCompletionHandler = null;
    return false;
}
```

**The app has runtime permissions to access the Gallery**. So what am I doing wrong? How to access the file on newer API versions?
    }

Comment: show the codes where the app asks the users to grant permission.

Comment: add runtime permission on above marshmallow devices

Comment: have you done run time permission in your app for external storage?

Comment: Yes, runtime permissions are granted (my code check this)

Answer (score 0):

try below code to open the camera and getting result:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FOTO_ACTION);
```

for getting result :

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {

                case PICK_FOTO_ACTION: {
                    Uri imageUri = imageUri;

                    File imgFile = new File(imageUri.getPath());
                    if (imgFile.exists())
                    // use the file...
                else
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image file not found",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

for getting actual path from uri :

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) 
    {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) return null;
        int column_index =             cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String s=cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
        return s;
    }
```

remove unwanted uri part :

```
public String RemoveUnwantedString(String pathUri){
    //pathUri = "content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/5213/ORIGINAL/NONE/2106970034"
    String[] d1 = pathUri.split("content://");
    for (String item1:d1) {
        if (item1.contains("media/")) {
            String[] d2 = item1.split("/ORIGINAL/");
            for (String item2:d2) {
                if (item2.contains("media/")) {
                    pathUri = "content://" + item2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    //pathUri = "content://media/external/video/media/5213"
    return pathUri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this has nothing to do with the question since I would like to pick an existing picture from the gallery and not take a new picture...

Comment: Sorry but could you describe in more detail how to apply this my question? Actually I would need just the `RemoveUnwantedString` method, right? This should be applied to `imageUri`? However the result also leeds to an non existing file...

Comment: first check in debug or in log that your uri is getting correct or not. if getting not in correct format, use RemoveUnwantedString() method else use getPath() method to get correct path of file from uri. @AndreiHerford

Answer (score -1):

For versions 21 and higher you can do this , you need to add a condition to check the SDK version for this. Exectute this code in the API 21+ condition block.

```
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(imageUri );
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    cursor =  
    getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                  projection, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);
    try
     {
      int column_index = cursor
           .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      path = cursor.getString(column_index).toString();
      cursor.close();
      }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {

      }
```

Comment: This throws an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider...` in the very first line when calling `DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(imageUri)`. BTW what is `projection` in `getContentResolver().query(..., projection, ...)`?

Answer (score -1):

> Call the Gallery with belo code

```
public static final int SELECT_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY_CODE = 701;
public static void callGallery(Activity activity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                SELECT_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY_CODE);
}
```

> In OnActivityResult, read URI and read path from uri.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CommonUtils.SELECT_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY_CODE) {

            if (data != null) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                // get path from Uri
                String imagepath = getPath(this, selectedImageUri);

                if (null != imagepath && (!imagepath.isEmpty())) {
                    // if the image path is not null and not empty, copy image to sdcard
                    try {
                        copyDirectoryOrFile(new File(imagepath), new File(myTargetImageFilePath));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // load the image into imageView with the help og glide.
                    loadImageWithGlide(myImageViewContactImage,
                            myTargetImageFilePath, myDefaultImagePath, myErrorImagePath, false);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,  "Error: Photo selection failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
}

public void loadImageWithGlide(ImageView theImageViewToLoadImage,
                                   String theLoadImagePath, int theDefaultImagePath, int theErrorImagePath,
                                   boolean theIsSkipMemoryCache) {

        if (theIsSkipMemoryCache) {
            Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this) //passing context
                    .load(theLoadImagePath) //passing your url to load image.
                    .placeholder(theDefaultImagePath) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                    .error(theErrorImagePath)//in case of any glide exception or not able to download then this image will be appear . if you won't mention this error() then nothing to worry placeHolder image would be remain as it is.
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                    //.animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(theImageViewToLoadImage); //pass imageView reference to appear the image.
        } else {
            Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this)
                    .load(theLoadImagePath)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(theImageViewToLoadImage);
        }
    }

    public static String getPath(Context theCtx, Uri uri) {
        try {
            Cursor cursor = (theCtx).getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
            document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
            cursor.close();

            cursor = (theCtx).getContentResolver().query(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            cursor.close();

            return path;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void copyDirectoryOrFile(File sourceLocation, File targetLocation)
            throws IOException {

        if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
            if (!targetLocation.exists() && !targetLocation.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Cannot create directory " + targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                copyDirectoryOrFile(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                        new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
            }
        } else {
            File directory = targetLocation.getParentFile();
            if (directory != null && !directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Cannot create directory " + directory.getAbsolutePath());

            }

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> To load image with glide, add following dependency in app gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```